# Move JPGs from a dir in home to a usb?

Tags: filesystem, filename

I'm using my raspberry pi to take pics of my 3d printer for time lapse. My only issue is that nothing I'm trying allows me to move them to the USB.

My most recent line I've tried:

```
~/Desktop/gphoto/images/Split $ mv -v * /media/pi/B0ED-02C5/Split/
```

I just keep getting the same errors for all the pics:

```
'2019-03-21 22: 46: 29 TL_Shots.JPG' -> '/media/pi/B0ED-02C5/Split/2019-03-21 22: 46: 29 TL_Shots.JPG'
mv: cannot create regular file '/media/pi/B0ED-02C5/Split/2019-03-21 22: 46: 29 TL_Shots.JPG': invalid argument
```

Comment: Whats your USB FlashDrive file system ?

Comment: You can check the USB filesystem via `lsblk --fs` Look for actual block device  and the mountpoint `/media/pi/B0ED-02C5` and whatever is the corresponding entry in FSTYPE column

Comment: Also, depending on your specific situation, questions related to Raspberry Pi may be more suitable on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/  Ask Ubuntu is more for questions related to Ubuntu OS and tools used on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

The error you get is typically related to the target filesystem
The usb device is probably FAT or NTFS witch does not allow special chars like `:` and so.

A quick workaround will be to modify the file naming pattern on your raspberry pictures taker.

And if you want to sanitize files names to make them accepted by Windows filesystem, here is a simple bash function to do it :

```
function sanitize_file_name {
    echo -n $1 | perl -pe 's/[\?\[\]\/\\=<>:;,''"&\$#*()|~`!{}%+]//g;' -pe 's/[\r\n\t -]+/-/g;'
}
```

Here is an example script that will move your files

```
#!/bin/bash
## -------- CONFIG ---------------------------------------------
PicsFolder=~/Desktop/gphoto/images/Split  ## Source Folder
DestFolder=/media/pi/B0ED-02C5/Split      ## Destination Folder
FILES=$PicsFolder/*.jpg                   ## File selection
## -------------------------------------------------------------
function sanitize_file_name {
    echo -n $1 | perl -pe 's/[\?\[\]\/\\=<>:;,''"&\$#*()|~`!{}%+]//g;' -pe 's/[\r\n\t -]+/-/g;'
}

OldIFS=$IFS;
NewIFS="
";
IFS=$NewIFS                               ## Handle spaces in filenames
for F in $FILES
    do
        mv $F $DestFolder/$(sanitize_file_name $(basename $F))
    done;
IFS=$OldIFS
```

Comment: Are you removing spaces in file names also? One could leave the spaces alone, provided the argument is quoted, i.e. instead of `mv -v * /medi...` -> `mv -v "*" /medi...`

Comment: To keep spaces simply remove the space in the last  regex `'s/[\r\n\t -]+/-/g;' -> 's/[\r\n\t-]+/-/g;'`